# python new line in txt file

Tags: python, newline

I have written some code to save usernames, passwords and email addresses in a text file.
by reading an email from an input text file and writing it with the other information to an output text file.

However, in the output file, new-lines are appearing after the email.

For example:

```
abcd@gmail.com
,name,user,pass
```

After changing the order of "`email`" and "`name`" it is happening again:

```
name,abcd@gmail.com
,user,pass.
```

My email file looks like:

```
abcd@gmail.com
abcde@gmail.com
...
```

How do I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance

My code:

```
line=""
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
f=open(r'C:\Users\11\Desktop\emailes.txt','r')

while True:
    password=id_generator()
    username=checkname()
    email=f.readline()
    if username !="":
            f2=open(r'C:\Users\11\Desktop\info.txt','a')
            f2.write(  email + "," + username + "," + username + "," + 
            password)
            f2.write("\n")
            driver.get("xxxx")
            assert "xxxx" in driver.title
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            elem=driver.find_element_by_name("email")
            elem.clear
            elem.send_keys(email)
            elem=driver.find_element_by_name("fullName")
            elem.clear
            elem.send_keys(username)
            elem=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
            elem.clear
            elem.send_keys(username)
            elem=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
            elem.clear
            elem.send_keys(password)
            elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            f2.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more precise.

Comment: See [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the string returned by the `readline` function will include the `\n` character.

Change:

```
email=f.readline()
```

to

```
email=f.readline().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the email, it gets an EOF ('\n') character because you are reading a line. You need to do this

```
email=f.readline().replace('\n','')
```

so you take off the EOF

Comment: Tnx my friend ;)